# PHP POST with header() and Bad header problems

Tags: php, http

I've come across a dumbfounding issue with sending headers in PHP. I've spent about 45 minutes reading on SO and other sites and I can't come up with a legitimate reason for my problem.

I need to send a POST request to another server and I'm using the PHP header() function to set the values.  I have sample code below.

```
    $server = 'http://fakedomain.com';
    $server_path = '/';
    $request = 'key=value&key2=value2';
    header("POST $server_path HTTP/1.1" );
    header("Host: $server\r\n" );
    header("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" );
    header("Content-length: ".strlen($request)."\r\n" );
    header("Connection: close\r\n\r\n" );
    header($request);
```

I've tried a variety of options but each of them results in the same error in my log file

```
malformed header from script. Bad header=POST / HTTP/1.1: php5.cgi
```

I'm an experience PHP programmer who just hasn't had much need to manually send HTTP post requests.

I want the code to redirect the browser so that's why I decided to use this method.

**Am I doing it right?**

**Is there some other way that is standard and I just don't know about?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

header() sends a *response* header.

It sounds like you want to make a *request*, on the back end.

So you probably want to use [curl](https://www.php.net/curl) to make the request.

If when you're done processing the response, you want to send some kind of header to the user agent (browser), then header() would be appropriate.

Comment: It's nice when you can learn something new.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The header functions relate to the headers returned to the client, I suggest you look into using cURL to do your post request: http://www.php.net/cURL

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect user to another page, you should use

```
header("Location: http://domain.com/some.other.page?x=y");
```

If you want the user to send POST variables to the redirect page you will need to use JavaScript.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Redirect</title>
</head>
<body onload="document.myform.submit()">
<form name="myform" action="http://domain.com/some.other.page" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="x" value="y">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on timdev's answer, here's the cURL you'd use:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.target.com/script.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "postvar1=value1&postvar2=value2&postvar3=value3");
curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried simple html form posting it worked for me

```
    <?php
    if( $dev === 'sample1' || $dev === 'sample2' )  {

?>
    <form name="frmpostdata" action="mystatement.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmsReq" value="MobApp" />
        <input type="hidden" name="cardno" value="<?php echo $chkTkn['cardno'];?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="cardPwd" value="<?php echo $chkTkn['pwd'];?>" />
        <input type="submit" style="display:none;" name="Submit" value="" />
    </form>
    <script>
        document.frmpostdata.submit();
    </script>
<?php   
        exit;
    }
    ?>
```