# displaying name on next page once email is sent

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form which sends to my email. Once form is complete and submitted it redirects to a email sent conformation page. I want to display the name on this page grabbing it from the field in which they inserted their name.

EMAIL FORM PHP:

```
<?php 
$your_email ='info@example.com';

session_start();
$errors = '';
$name = '';
$visitor_email = '';
$user_message = '';

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
    $user_message = $_POST['message'];
    ///------------Do Validations-------------

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
header('Location: emailsent.php?name=' . $name);
```

In emailsent.php

```
echo $_GET['name'];
```

Comment: thanks and if i wanted to get email address aswell would i do header('Location: emailsent.php?name=' . $name, email=' . $email);

Comment: You can use: `header('Location: emailsent.php?name='.$name.'&email='. $email);

Comment: yes indeed, also good to remember when using header() php continues to execute the remaining statements after the header() call. So it's a good idea to stick an exit; afterwards unless you specifically don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

May I ask why are you using `header('Location: emailsent.php');`? instead of using header you can reload the same page and modify it to show a different content if the email was sent.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && empty($errors)) {
    //show a success message and some html code... e.g.:
    echo 'Thank you, '.$_POST['name']; //this is the senders name
}
?>
```

If you must use headers, [here is a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653090/how-do-you-post-to-a-page-using-the-php-header-function)