# PHP HTTP Header to send POST data

Tags: php, http-headers, postdata

Is there a way to send POST data using HTTP headers without a form from PHP?

Comment: PHP runs on the server side.  Do you mean "from javascript"?

Comment: is something like this what ur looking for?
[Post to a page using PHP header function][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653090/how-do-you-post-to-a-page-using-the-php-header-function

Comment: I know php is server side, but you can set headers. EX: header("location: http://google.com")

Comment: Like cURL you mean? http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: Sort of, except my host won't allow adding extensions to the PHP installation; is there any way to send a value without using a form, $_GET, $_SESSION, $_COOKIES (I don't want it to be saved or shown anywhere)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can create a valid http request with your specified POST parameters easily using a library like cURL.

See [this](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-curl-form-post/) for a curl example

If you are limited to plain PHP you can create your own (valid) http-request, see [example](http://www.ajaxapp.com/2010/03/15/php-how-to-http-post-without-using-curl/)