# PUT/DELETE header redirect

Tags: php, api, rest

I'm trying to do a header redirect in PHP doing something like:

```
header("Location: http://www.domain.com/some/url");
exit;
```

This works fine when making a GET and POST request however it doesn't seem to work with PUT and DELETE requests.

I've tried doing:

```
header("Location: DELETE/PUT http://www.domain.com/some/url");
exit;
```

But that doesn't seem to work, also calling the url directly works fine.  I can echo some text before and after the header call, so everything is working, seems to just ignore PUT and DELETE requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/653102/1156688), possible same answer applies to you

> The header function is used to send HTTP response headers back to the
>   user (i.e. you cannot use it to create request headers.
>
> May I ask why are you doing this? Why simulate a POST request when you
>   can just right there and then act on the data someway? I'm assuming of
>   course script.php resides on your server.
>
> To create a POST request, open a up a TCP connection to the host using
>   fsockopen(), then use fwrite() on the handler returned from
>   fsockopen() with the same values you used in the header functions in
>   the OP. Alternatively, you can use cURL.

PS: I see that it is also displayed under `Linked` tab :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `Location` is not the proper way to set the HTTP Method header.

Try the following:

```
header("Request-Type: DELETE");
header("Location: http://www.domain.com/some/url");
exit;
```

However, I am not sure you can set request types with `header()` alone. I know you can with cURL.