# php request forwarder which can forward request to some asp.net ashx handler

Tags: php

Can I somehow build request forwarder type functionality in php.
Problem is that previously i have some .net ashx handler which works as callbackhandler. Different client send differnt type of request like some send post request some send json and some send simple request withinfo in querystring.
Now I want's to create a page which simple forward all the headers,querystring,form postelement, json to my ashx handler. is something like this possible

Comment: You could do this with cUrl. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886600/php-forward-post-variables-to-other-page

Comment: What about `mod_rewrite`?

Comment: not heard of mod_rewrite