# Post to server with php and not explode the respond

Tags: php, http

I need to post values to a server. The server will respond with a webpage. I do not want to read the response and echo to a page. I only want to post and let the server display by itself. `"header(location:bla bla)"` is a "get" I can't used it. With `Curl` or `pear`, I will need to explode the response and display it (is a no,no). Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

what about automatically submitting a form (method="POST") with javascript?

Comment: I'm posting secure values. Can't be display to browser.

Comment: then you might want to take a look at this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653090/how-do-you-post-to-a-page-using-the-php-header-function

Comment: Yeah I read that one before. Is not help they adv to used curl or to captured and echo. :(

Answer (score 1):

Your question is hard for me to parse, although I tried my best and I also edited it for others.

I think what you may be looking for is the following. For example, if you wanted to display a plaintext file directly in the browser:

```
// Do processing above...
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
echo $text;
exit;
```

This will have your browser output the data as if it were a text document, not an HTML page.

But, say you want to do something more exotic? Like output a PNG image?

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo $pngData;
exit;
```

I hope that helps. Search online for `MIME Types` to find more of these values for other file types.

Comment: You aren't even close of what i need to accomplish here. But hey thx anyway.

Comment: Well, blame yourself, buddy. Your question is incredibly hard to parse.